# Acceder a un model desde el controller de un ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy usando ASP.NET MVC4 y encuentro dificultad a la hora de traer datos almacenados en las tablas de la base de datos.

Entiendo que existen algunas clausulas `ToList()` que podrían listar los datos, pero actualmente los métodos que uso siempre me devuelven `null`.

El codigo que estoy implementando actualmente es:

**Controller (ViewModel):**

```
    public ActionResult EditForm()
   {
        FormularioFlota2 FF2 = new FormularioFlota2();
        FF2.FormularioFlota_Persona = GetPersona();
        return View(FF2);
    }

    public DbSet<Persona> DbPersonas { get; set; }

    public List<Persona> GetPersona()
    {
        List<Persona> listaDePersonasPrueba = new List<Persona>();
        listaDePersonasPrueba = DbPersonas.ToList();


        return listaDePersonasPrueba;
    }
```

**View (ViewModel):**

```
 @if (Model.FormularioFlota_Persona != null && Model.FormularioFlota_Persona.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.FormularioFlota_Persona)
                {
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @item.Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.NumeroLegajo
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Nombre
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Apellido
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Calle
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Localidad
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Provincia
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Telefono
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Email
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Documento
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Cuil
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.EstadoCivil
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Cargo
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.SectorId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.GrupoBeneficiarioId
                </td>
            </tr>
                    }
                }
```

> Nota: por alguna razón los Tags `TD` Y `TR` no me los detecta como
>   texto, por eso en el View Se ve todo pegado, pero básicamente recorro
>   el vector `FormularioFlotaPersona` y asigno los campos, es ahí cuando
>   me falla, el compilador me indica que recibe "`null`"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno conoce un método que pueda aplicar en un controller (de viewmodel) para traer todos los datos almacenados en una tabla? Tengo todas las tablas definidas en distintos modelos y funcionando correctamente. Lo ideal seria evitar el uso de comandos Queryable.

Comment: buen día, creo que estás mezclando varias cosas, revisa este workshop que hice para que tengas un mejor panorama de cómo trabajar con ASP net MVC :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY (incluye el código fuente)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu controlador debes tener a tus entidades:

```
private BaseDeDatosEntities db = new BaseDeDatosEntities(); 
//o como lo hayas definido en el Context
```

Una recomendación en el siguiente ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult EditForm()
{
    //Cada vez que vayas a pasar un model:
    //utiliza la misma palabra para que te sea más fácil de identificarlos.
    FormularioFlota2 model = new FormularioFlota2();
    model.FormularioFlota_Persona = GetPersona();
    return View(model);
}
```

Aqui cuando traes las entidades, asegurate primero llamar a las entidades y dentro de ellas se encuentra la tabla con la que quieres trabajar, porque te saltas ese detalle, es porque te sale todo null.

```
public List<Persona> GetPersona()
{
    List<Persona> listaDePersonasPrueba = new List<Persona>();
    listaDePersonasPrueba = db.DbPersonas.ToList();
    return listaDePersonasPrueba;
}
```

Detalles adicionales:

1. En los ActionResults donde vas a modificar información, se recomienda tener el formulario de la tabla/entidad que vas a modificar.
2. Si vas a listar para luego modificar, dicha lista puede ir tranquilamente en un ActionResult diferente.
3. Recuerda utilizar **DataAnnotations de EntityFramework** + **jQuery unobtrusive** para que se te haga la vida más sencilla al momento de realizar las validaciones de inputs.
4. Lleva unas clases de ASP.net MVC en http://mva.microsoft.com/ - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/index.htm

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas. El problema que estoy teniendo justamente es que no puedo implementar "db."     Alguno sabe que libreria tiene dicha palabra reservada? Saludos.

Comment: de nada hermano, "db" es el nombre que le he asignado a mis entidades, cuál enfoque estás siguiendo? Code First o DataBase First o Model First? Ayudaria mucho si editas tu pregunta y le agregas la estructura de tu proyecto. Saludos :D

Comment: digamos que soy nuevo, conozco lo basico de mvc, asi que no sabria discriminar entre Code First, DataBase First y Model First. Me queda la duda de "db." por que lo vi en muchos ejemplos, pero no logro entender como aplicarlo... Por lo pronto cuando hago "DbPersonas.ToList()" me devuelve "null", por alguna razon no va a buscar los datos a la tabla, sino que me crea una nueva entidad del tipo "Persona".

Comment: con mayor razón revisa el video del workshop que hice :D lo hice para gente que recién anda iniciando :D el video incluye errores catastróficos de esos que son para llorar hahahaha y maneras de analizar para su solución :D te recomiendo que prepares pop-corn y unos refrescos porque son 4 horas 4 minutos y 4 segundos. Ahora bien, para solucionar tu problema, agrega la infomación que te he solicitado en tu pregunta, click aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/66822/edit

Comment: Gracias por toda la ayuda, por desgracia ahora no puedo subir lo que me pides, ademas de que son demasiados archivos para revisar. No obstante y viendo el codigo fuente del ejemplo vi que instancias como "db" a aquella clase que hereda de ": DbContext" y con ello puede acceder a la base de datos sin problemas. Voy a probar hacer eso y ver como me va :)

Comment: de nada hermano :D estamos para crecer entre todos, esta industria avanza gracias a que muchos de nosotros aportamos y compartimos con todo el gusto del mundo :D sé que si seguimos así, hispanoamérica será potencia en producción de software :D #ConTodoElPower2.0! éxitos con el desarrollo!